# method delete is not allowed by access-control-allow-methods angularjs

Tags: http, cors

I have developed app using angularjs and ionic-framework. When I try to delete an item from list Im getting an error:

`Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.`

I searched what this means but couldn't get a proper explanation. So have posted this query here, hope I will get help. Thank you.

Comment: The CORS configuration of your sever needs to be updated to accept DELETE requests.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is on server side. You need to send proper access control headers.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE
```

Example in PHP:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
```